# $\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{1}{x_j-x_i}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{1}{x_j-x_i} = 0$ for distinct $x's$? I tried for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ and these are true. But I cannot generalize it for natural number $n$. I just tried mathematical induction, but it was also difficult. Anyone know this equation?
(I don't know what tags are going with, so if you have a good idea, change it please.)

Comment: This needs some clarification - which values of j are considered in the product? All natural numbers excluding i?

Comment: j's are 1, 2, ... , n except for i.